# How to access Users and Groups data from SAP BO 4.1

Tags: business-objects, sapb1

I am new to SAP and doesn't understand its basics. I believe that SAP allows the data access via webservices. Where can I get the list of services that allows me to access the 'users and groups' ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this an SAP Business Objects question or an SAP Business One question?

Comment: @Overhed :- SAP Business Object

Comment: Ok, you used the wrong tag (sapb1). I just adjusted this. I don't know if you're going to get a lot of help on here. Your best bet might be SCN (scn.sap.com).

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that you can access this kind of data, from a WebService.
On the BI platform, there is a REST API for this kind of operations

It is well documented in their own documentation, but you could also for a starter, take a look at my blog post her https://blogs.sap.com/2016/02/08/use-microsoft-powershell-to-manage-your-bi-platform/ and check out the example I've made in GitHub https://github.com/Verakso/BO-PowerShell